Glitter before gloss varnish, or gloss varnish before glitter (or something else entirely)?
I'm making a moderately sized scale model of Cinderella's pumpkin coach.
I want it to have a high gloss finish with glitter highlights on the edges and details.
My intention is to coat it in several thin coats of high gloss varnish, lightly sand it in between, and then polish/wax it in much the same way as a piece of furniture with a high gloss finish.
On one hand, applying the glitter before the varnish could potentially create a rough surface that would - at the very least - snag on my polishing cloth or be eroded by sanding.
On the other hand, applying the glitter after the varnish would require applying a matte finish glue to a high gloss surface.
Which order would produce the best finish, or is there a third solution that I could use?
I do not have the budget available for expensive after-market products such as speed boat glitter finishes.

I would apply the glitter between two of the coats of high gloss varnish.
Why?
Your first coat of high gloss varnish will be your most difficult coat.  So no need to make it more difficult by adding glitter to the equation.
After your first coat, you'll have a smooth surface on which the glitter particles will lay more flat.  This will aid in not snagging on your polishing cloth later on.
If you apply the glitter after all the coats of varnish, I think you'll be unhappy with the results.  That matte finish glue is going to take away from all the hard work you put in creating the previous high gloss varnish coats.
By applying the glitter between coats, it won't flake off or create a rough surface.
Have fun!

I'd like to add that the type of glitter used will also influence the result. There are thousands of different types, made from different materials, in different thicknesses and sizes. I think the thickness of the glitter particles is the biggest problem here. You'll want a very thin (foil?) glitter that adheres to the surface and doesn't create ridges along the edge for the polishing cloth to snag on.

On a test piece, I'd try a few things, in the order that would look most glittery:

Varnish fully, apply dry glitter where required after the varnish has barely started to dry (risks: most varnish might not be good enough glue, what with not being glue; dry glitter goes where it wants rather than where you want)
Varnish fully, allow to dry, mix fine glitter into more varnish and apply where required.  Again, varnish isn't glue but this way coats the glitter better and should bind it better, but it may not sparkle quite as much.  It's also easy to apply precisely and will be smoother.  You can apply more varnish on top. This is probably the most polishable so ought to be the best fit overall.
Varnish fully, apply glitter with glue - but the glue is likely to look dull
Varnish over the top of the previous step.  I suspect that the glue still won't look great, and the varnish may not adhere very well to it.

